# Send Image from api to client Elixir Phonix

Tags: elixir

image is store local
when i try this way mention below

```
  def render("per_view.json", %{album: album}) do
    %{data: %{
        Tilte: album.title,
        Artist: album.artist,
        image: resolved_image(album)
      }
    }
  end

  def resolved_image(album) do
     {:ok, image} = AlbumApi.ImageUploader.store({%Plug.Upload{}, album})
     image
  end
end
```

it give error 
no function clause matching in IO.chardata_to_string/1

when i used this way

```
def render("per_view.json", %{album: album}) do
    %{data: %{
        Tilte: album.title,
        Artist: album.artist,
        image: AlbumApi.ImageUploader.url({album.image, album})
      }
    }
  end
```

it give the path not the image

```
{
    "data": {
        "image": "/uploads/9ddaf02ea49208183eb77fe3560770e3--music-album-covers-music-albums.jpg?v=63683254541",
        "Tilte": "Messi",
        "Artist": "Link PArk"
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to archive? Where is your problem?

Comment: need to get image from api in my mobile